# jQuery handler for closing a login box

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

I'm sure there's a better more 'jQuery' like way of writing this.  In particular the selector `$(this).closest('div.login-box')` being in there twice. Perhaps it's possible to use `$(this)`?

```
$('.close-box').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('div.login-box').slideToggle("400");
        if ($(this).closest('div.login-box').attr('id') == "login-forgot") {
            clearForgottenPasswordInputs();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the calls:

```
if ($(this).closest('div.login-box')
           .slideToggle("400")
           .attr('id'))
```

However, I do not recommend this.
Although it will work, it's unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I dunno... if he just did `loginbox_id = $(this).closest('div.login-box').slideToggle("400").attr('id');` Then he could just do `if (loginbox_id == "login-forgot")` below it. I think it removes any confusion that may occur by placing animation calls inside a boolean statement.

Comment: @day: Yes.  However, it's still confusing to have a mutation and a property access in the same line.